# Make content of a table cell bigger than the cell without changing the cell's width

Tags: html, css

As the title might be confusing I'm gonna explain what I mean using some pictures.

Here's what my situation looks like:
[image: This is what my situation looks like]

All this is inside of a table and the boxes all take up the width of the table. But what I need to achieve is that the data field grows to the full width of the screen under certain conditions, because the content can be very much. This should look like that:
[image]

Of course, as the whole stuff is in a table, changing the width of the data field also changes the width of the table cell and therefore the width of the other cells as well, which causes the textboxes and listboxes to grow as well:
[image]

So is there any way to keep the cells at a fixed size while making the data field grow over the borders of the cell/table? I thought about using positioning or something, but it doesn't really work out. And I cannot change the table layout as this isn't my work and I'm only "cleaning it up" pretty much.

Comment: Why are you using a table? You'll have much more control over individual elements if you take a different approach!

Comment: I also hate using a table, but as I already wrote I'm not allowed to change it sadly. It's terrible.

Comment: I'm not convinced there is any easy solution to your problem without doing so..

Comment: You can use no of columns and then use colspan accordingly to stop other fields to expand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about applying max-width for the tds so that they don't expand?

```css
table {
    border-spacing: 0px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
table td {
    max-width: 100px; /* applied max-widht here */
    border: 1px solid red;
}
table input {
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#dd {
    width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select id="dd">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you, I knew there had to be an easy solution! I'm always thinking much too complicated.